# Rate calculation in SQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

right now, I really have no idea how could I solve this.

I have users who can deal with a different types of tasks.

> These tasks have many properties. I chose **just 4** property for **simplicity**.

If I assign a task to a user, I have to give a rate to this assignment. This rate will determine how much I have to pay for him, when he finished his task.

I have the following table. These id fields are **nullable** (except user_id), and all of them are **foreign keys**.

```
|-#-|-user_id-|-type_id-|-task_id-|-source_id-|-target_id-|--rate--|
| 1 |   12    |   NULL  |    1    |     1     |     2     | 0.0022 |
| 2 |   12    |   NULL  |    2    |     1     |     2     | 0.0101 |
| 3 |   12    |   NULL  |    1    |     2     |     1     | 0.0200 |
| 4 |   12    |   NULL  |    2    |     2     |     1     | 0.1011 |
| 5 |   12    |    1    |   NULL  |    NULL   |    NULL   | 0.0750 |
| 6 |   12    |    2    |    1    |    NULL   |    NULL   | 0.0520 |
| 7 |   12    |   NULL  |    1    |    NULL   |    NULL   | 0.9100 |
```

Of course there are rates for other users too.

There is now weights, just left to right order (**from column type_id**).

**But:** it is important that: **To the left** from the first column match, have to be all **equal to the assigned task values or NULL** values. **To the right** have to be **equal to the assigned task values or NULL**

#### Example 1

```
user_id: 12
type_id: 3
task_id: 2
source_id: 1
target_id: 2
```

**#2 - 0.0101** rate should be selected.

#### Example 2

```
user_id: 12
type_id: 1
task_id: 2
source_id: 3
target_id: 4
```

**#5 - 0.0750** rate should be selected.

#### Example 3

```
user_id: 12
type_id: 2
task_id: 1
source_id: 2
target_id: 3
```

**#6 - 0.0520** rate should be selected.

So far, I'm ok with this. But I can't solve the following:

#### Example 4

```
user_id: 12
type_id: 2
task_id: 2
source_id: 2
target_id: 3
```

**NONE** should be selected.

#### Example 5

```
user_id: 12
type_id: 3
task_id: 1
source_id: 2
target_id: 3
```

**NONE** should be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `order by` and `fetch first row`:

```
select t.*
from t
where user_id = 12 and
      (type_id = 3 or type_id is null) and
      (task_id = 2 or task_id is null) and
      (source_id = 1 or source_id is null) and
      (target_id = 2 or target_id is null)
order by ( (type_id is not null)::int +
           (task_id is not null)::int +
           (source_id is not null)::int +
           (target_id is not null)::int
         ) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This returns the row that matches your conditions, but with the fewest `NULL` values (that is, the most specific row).

EDIT:

If you need to match them in order, then the `where` clause looks like:

```
order by (type_id is not null)::int desc,
         (task_id is not null)::int desc,
         (source_id is not null)::int desc,
         (target_id is not null)::int desc
```

Comment: It solves party. But if I got 2 row. I have to get the that row, which has a match earlier, from left to right. So I altered your query:
`select t.*
from t
where user_id = 12 and
      (type_id = 3 or type_id is null) and
      (task_id = 2 or task_id is null) and
      (source_id = 1 or source_id is null) and
      (target_id = 2 or target_id is null)
order by type_id is not null desc,
              task_id is not null desc,
              source_id is not null desc,
              target_id is not null desc
fetch first 1 row only;`

**TL;DR:** type_id is not null desc ... etc

Comment: @ZoltánFekete . . . I wasn't sure if the matching was ordered or majority based.

Comment: Exactly, that solved. I already ordered the list but not this way. But that "hack" `column is not null or column = 2` is my relief. :D Thanks